# What should I use for representing sets in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, set

I want to do some work with sets in Prolog. I found that there's a library in SWI called `ordsets` which seems to be what I'm looking for, but then I tried it out:

```
?- is_ordset([X]), is_ordset([1]).
true.
```

Okay, `[X]` and `[1]` are considered to be ordered sets. So far so good.

```
?- is_ordset([X]), is_ordset([1]), ord_union([1], [Y], Set).
Set = [Y, 1].
```

Alright, the union of these two ordered sets is `[Y, 1]`. That's kinda okay, but then...

```
?- is_ordset([X]), is_ordset([1]), ord_union([1], [Y], Set), Y = 2.
Y = 2,
Set = [2, 1].
```

That doesn't look right, it's not ordered.

```
?- is_ordset([X]), is_ordset([1]), ord_union([1], [Y], Set), Y = 2, is_ordset(Set).
false.
```

Yep, it's not an ordered set. What exactly is the point of this library if you can't even use it logically? What should I be using instead? The Prolog system I'm using is SWI, but I see this:

http://www.picat-lang.org/bprolog/manual/node115.html

Would that work any better? I guess it's part of B Prolog. What is the best way to reason about sets logically?

Comment: You need to read the [documentation](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=ordsets). `Note however, that the ordering is not stable if a term inside the set is further instantiated`

Comment: What is the set supposed to contain? Only integer or _any_ term?

Answer (score 0):

Prolog gives us the ability to use uninstantiated variables, which can be very flexible, but can also be a can of worms for the unwary.

If you add 2 *uninstantiated* variables to a list, then later give them values which violate being an ordered set, then there's nothing built into Prolog or the [ordsets library](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=ordsets) that will magically fix it behind the scenes for you. It's merely a list structure, and values can't change once they are assigned - with some exceptions ([setarg](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=setarg/3)).

What you can do, is simply use [sort](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sort/2) on your list, which will quickly sort it and remove duplicates, resulting in a new list.

Or, you can use e.g. `ord_add_element` with an *instantiated* variable.